# Не выводится ссылка для реплаев в wordpress. В чем причина?

Tags: wordpress

С помощью функции `wp_list_comments()` вывожу комментарии. Определил `callback` функцию для вывода каждого комментария. И в этой функции использую `comment_reply_link()`, но ничего не выводит. Пробовал `get_comment_reply_link()` - тоже ничего.

Пробовал подставлять в аргументы номер текущего комментария и `id` страницы, ничего не дало. Ставил в массив аргументов `'depth' => 5`, как советовали в гугле, но ничего.

Остальные функции работают нормально. `edit_comment_link` и прочие.
На странице настроек вордпресс древовидные комментарии включены, уровень вложенности укаазан 5. На самой странице (комментарии к которой и вывожу) комментарии разрешены.

вот так вывожу комменты на странице page-review (шаблон страницы где хочу вывести комментарии):

```
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
</div>
```

файл comments.php (полностью):

```html
<?php
  $args = array(
    'walker'            => null,
    'style'             => 'ol',
    'callback'          => 'mytheme_comment',
    'end-callback'      => null,
    'type'              => 'all',
    'reply_text'        => 'Reply',
    'page'              => '',
    'per_page'          => '',
    'avatar_size'       => 32,
    'reverse_top_level' => null,
    'reverse_children'  => '',
    'format'            => 'html5', // или xhtml, если HTML5 не поддерживается темой
    'short_ping'        => false,    // С версии 3.6,
    'echo'              => true,     // true или false
  );
?>

<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
  <ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments($args); ?>
  </ol>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php 
function mytheme_comment($comment, $args, $depth) { ?>

  <li id="li-comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID ?>" <?php comment_class(); ?>>
    <article id="comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" class="comment-article">
      <header class="comment-meta">
        <div class="comment-author vcard">
          <cite class="fn"><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?></cite>
        </div>
        <?php
          $date = $comment->comment_date;
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_Comment_link(); ?>">
          <time datetime="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)); ?>T<?php echo date("h:m:s", strtotime($date)); ?>">
            <?php echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime($date)); ?>
          </time>
        </a>
        <div class="comment-tools">
          <?php edit_comment_link(); ?>
          <?php $replyArgs = array('depth' => '5'); ?>
          <?php comment_reply_link(); ?>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="entry-content comment-content">
        <p><?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?></p>
      </div>
    </article>

<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества, вам необходимо привести код.

Comment: Добавил примеры кода